# Need to mock exported constant instance

Tags: typescript, jestjs

How to mock  `export const dependendantService`? so that I can return a mock result for `dependendantService.list`?
the list has `get` method but it is read-only.

Tried by mocking module or using `jest.spyOn(dependendantService, 'list', 'get')` but getting error

> Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given

Typescript class

External module

dependency-service-instance.ts

```
import { DependencyService} from './dependency-service';

export const dependendantService = new DependencyService();
```

My Module

my-service.ts

```
export function myFunction(): string{

      // consuming here 

         const list = dependendantService.list;

       // doing something

}
```

Testing my service using jest

my-service-test.ts

```js
describe('test1', () => {
  it('return string, if dependendantService is not giving empty list', () => {
    expect(myFunction()).toBe('xyz');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock `getter` for `list` use `jest.spyOn`. Here is the solution:

Folder structure:

```sh
.
├── dependency-service-instance.ts
├── dependency-service.ts
├── my-service.spec.ts
└── my-service.ts
```

`dependency-service.ts`:

```js
export class DependencyService {
  private _list: any[] = [];
  public get list(): any[] {
    return this._list;
  }
}
```

`dependency-service-instance.ts`:

```js
import { DependencyService } from './dependency-service';

export const dependendantService = new DependencyService();
```

`my-service.ts`:

```js
import { dependendantService } from './dependency-service-instance';

export function myFunction(): string {
  const list = dependendantService.list;
  if (!list.length) {
    throw new Error('list is empty');
  }
  return 'xyz';
}
```

`my-service.spec.ts`:

```js
import { myFunction } from './my-service';
import { dependendantService } from './dependency-service-instance';

describe('myFunction', () => {
  it('return string, if dependendantService is not giving empty list', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(dependendantService, 'list', 'get').mockReturnValueOnce([{}]);
    const actualValue = myFunction();
    expect(actualValue).toBe('xyz');
    expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    spy.mockRestore();
  });

  it('throw erorr, if dependendantService is giving empty list', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(dependendantService, 'list', 'get').mockReturnValueOnce([]);
    expect(() => myFunction()).toThrowError(new Error('list is empty'));
    expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    spy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58073589/my-service.spec.ts (9.08s)
  myFunction
    ✓ return string, if dependendantService is not giving empty list (5ms)
    ✓ throw erorr, if dependendantService is giving empty list (3ms)

--------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                            |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files                       |    92.86 |      100 |    66.67 |    92.31 |                   |
 dependency-service-instance.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 dependency-service.ts          |    83.33 |      100 |       50 |       80 |                 4 |
 my-service.ts                  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
--------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.806s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58073589